# How to set up a CRON Task to only run once per set of instances?

Tags: java, tomcat, cron, scheduled-tasks, cluster-computing

We are hosting our website in AWS. We currently have 3 EC2 instances in one cluster, using the AWS load balancer.

The servers have linux, apache, java, mysql, and tomcat 6.0.

We are making a decision on how to set up a task to run every hour. The obvious place to do this is in the Java code, but there is one problem.

The problem is that since we have 3 instances in the cluster (all are identical), the task will run 3 times on the hour, instead of once an hour, once per instance.

I have a few ideas to overcome this but was hoping that there is a better, possibly an industry standard, on how to manage this.

One idea is to store in the DB that it has already run. The task will see that it has already ran today or not. I see bugs there though.

The other idea was to use cron installed on one of the instances in the native OS, outside of the code in Tomcat. This would use wget to call a webpage which calls a java method. Since that would only call one of the instances, it should only run once.

Both ways seem like hacks and prone to bugs. Is there a real way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used the cron/wget solution and it's actually a reasonable way to solve the problem.   Your system administrators will appreciate being able to control it.

Another solution is to use a JVM system property to indicate which of your instances is the one that runs the jobs. For example: `-DschedulerEnabled=true`.  Only set that flag on one of the instances and have the job scheduling code only run if that flag is set.

Finally, Quartz supports your DB based solution with it's [Clustering](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering) feature.   The advantage of this is that it's a really a HA solution.  With the other solutions if the machine that is acting as the job scheduler goes down you have to manually fail over to another machine.

Comment: Also, just found rcron which may solve it as well: https://code.google.com/p/rcron/

Answer (score 5):

While there's an accepted answer, there are some simple, homegrown solutions which don't have the bugs as you outlined above. The wget solution works well to ensure a single server runs the code, but adds issues of security (you should secure the URL with a shared, private access key), and as @sourcedelica pointed out also the issue of which server should then actually invoke the cron task.

I tend to go for the solution which works regardless of the number of systems you have - and also doesn't require different cron configurations for different systems.

The assumption is that down the road you may add new machines, and your primary server (the one configured to run your cron task, for example) may die or be terminated.

A solution I've developed uses cluster database locks which can be done with a two simple tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Server` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `alive` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Lock` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `code` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `pid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `server` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `locked` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `used` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
);
```

Each system has a unique `uname`, and registers a record if it doesn't exist; updating `alive` each time.

To acquire a lock:

```
SELECT * FROM Lock WHERE code='cron-cluster';
```

If it doesn't exist,

```
INSERT INTO `Lock` ...
```

Once you have your `Lock` with `id` of 32. If `server` and `pid` are both NULL, set them to my server `id` and current process id, using the atomic nature of the database to ensure only one.

```
UPDATE Lock SET server=1,pid=4233 WHERE id=32 AND server IS NULL and pid IS NULL;
```

Then you do a select again to see if you actually acquired it (assuming that n different machines are trying to acquire the lock at the same time):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Lock WHERE code='cron-cluster' AND server=1 AND pid=4233;
```

If the result is 1, you've acquire the lock, 0 means another process did.

The final thing needed is to have each server clean off dead locks and dead servers; each server is responsible for checking that an active process is running for each locked `Lock`, and when a `Server` is not updated as `alive` after a certain time out, delete all locks associated with that server and its `Server` record.

I added other server properties to the `Server` table to allow monitoring of disk space, CPU, etc.

While not as powerful as Quartz clustering, it solves your problem.

Comment: Love your work, this one gave me the insight I was lacking to figure it out.

I went slightly more simple, using MySQL the cron can be run at any frequent interval, I went with 4 hours:

`"UPDATE lock SET server=1, lock_date=NOW() WHERE lock_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR; SELECT ROW_COUNT();"`

2 queries sent at once and if it hasn't updated to be the current server perform no action